# Android stop permission promt for screen recording

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am running some experiments where I need my workflow to be automated.
One of the tasks involves launching an android application I've made. This app records the display of the device and then after a minute or so, the app is killed via ADB.

Because the app is recording the screen, it prompts the user, saying:

[image]

I get that it is a security feature, but for testing or experimental purposes, is there any way to disable it or perhaps simulate the "Start now" click?

I've tried `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROJECT_MEDIA"/>` but it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Can't get rid of the dialog, but I can simulate a tap event at the location of the "Start now" button.

To do this, go to `Developer Options` and enable `Pointer Location`. This will show the coordinates of touch events in the top menu bar.

Open the app showing the dialog, tap the "Start now" button and note the coordinates of the touch event.

Now when you need to automatically accept the permissions, run the following ADB command:

`adb shell input tap x y` where `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the touch event.

Comment: how can we make it generic for all other device? and does adb commands works for you?

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani I don't know - it worked for my needs so I did not look for  a generic way. I didn't try the adb commands since that answer cam 5 months after my question, so by that time I had already solved my problem. Try the adb commands and please let us know if they work.

Answer (score 13):

You can disable it using the following [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) command:

```
adb shell appops set com.your.app.id PROJECT_MEDIA allow
```

To revert, set it to `ignore`.

Comment: Great. This works for Anydesk. (First get list of the app id with `./adb shell pm list packages anyd`, then applied it for `./adb shell appops set com.anydesk.anydeskandroid PROJECT_MEDIA allow` and `./adb shell appops set com.anydesk.adcontrol.ad1 PROJECT_MEDIA allow`